# Client side data binding is possible in asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net

please discuss if Client side data binding is possible in asp.net 4.0 and also show me how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends on what you are trying to bind...  It also varies depending on whether you are using web forms or MVC.  There is a host of great resources on this web site: http://www.asp.net/web-forms.  They also have an MVC resource if you are on that platform.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing should have changed since ASP.net 1

```
<%# Container.DataItem("yourcolumn") %>
```

or

```
<%# Eval("yourcolumn") %>
```